# How to migrate data to new table with some default value from old table in SQL

Tags: sql, sqlalchemy-migrate

I have table User with field username, password. I want to create tracking_user table with these field: username, password, custom, time. How can I create SQL script to create tracking_user with username, password from user table and custom have default value 0 and time is now when running script. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that you need to create 3 different SQL queries like below.

**1) Clone your user table structure**

```
CREATE TABLE tracking_user LIKE user;
```

**2) Add additional column to new table**

```
ALTER TABLE tracking_user ADD custom INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' AFTER password, ADD time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AFTER custom;
```

**3) Clone your user table data to new table**

```
INSERT INTO tracking_user (username, password) SELECT username, password FROM user;
```

Comment: @MIM I hope it becomes helpful for you.